# JSON as attribute in sequlize not working for Postgres

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

my query is to fetch data from a table according to JSON

```
var jsondata="{'job_media','job_quote','job_invoice', 'job_client','created_by', 'job_status', 'job_source', 'job_job_template_name', 'job_job_template_data'}";
Jobs.findOne({
    attributes: [jsondata],
    where: { job_id: id}
  });
```

But it's not working, we can change JSON data in any style but should be JSON.

Comment: I don't think it's a valid JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I was wrong with my json.this is right json 
// a JSON array
["one", "two", "three"]

// a JSON object
{ "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3 }

    Query :
    Jobs.findOne({
        attributes: ['job_media', 'job_quote', 'job_invoice', 'job_client', 'created_by', 'job_status', 'job_source', 'job_job_template_name', 'job_job_template_data'],
        where: { job_id: id },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attributes` option can have several different [shapes](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll), but it looks like you just want to pass a flat array of strings.

So your query should look like:

```js
Jobs.findOne({
    attributes: ['job_media', 'job_quote', 'job_invoice', 'job_client', 'created_by', 'job_status', 'job_source', 'job_job_template_name', 'job_job_template_data'],
    where: { job_id: id },
});
```

See the section titled [Specifying attributes for SELECT queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries) for more information.